# Trim video into multiple sections ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, video-encoding

I need to trim a video into multiple sections of unequal duration and output them as separate files.

For example a `.mp4` 100 seconds long and I need to extract and keep

- output0.mp4 from 5 - 10sec
- output1.mp4 from 10 - 20 sec
- output2.mp4 from 35 - 60 sec

Current Solution:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy  -t 5  output0.mp4 -ss 10 -c copy -t 10 output1.mp4 -ss 20 -c copy -ss 35 t 60  output2.mp4 -y
```

Current solution works but is there a way to group process and index the output with a format specifier?
Something like below or an alternative method without re-encoding?

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4  -c copy -t 5 -ss 10  -t 10 -ss 20 -y output%d.mp4
```

My alternative solution using `segment` has the problem that it also returns an `output3.mp4` from 60 - 100sec and the durations aside from `output0.mp4` do not match the expected values.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 5,10,20,35,60 output%d.mp4
```

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same thing